# XML validator using XSD 1.1

Tags: xml

Is there any software (application/library) which validates *.xml against XSD 1.1 (assert etc.) through script?

Ideally, I 'm searching for an open source solution or a product that doesn't need a paid license.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three implementations of XSD 1.1 that I'm aware of:

- [Altova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altova)
- [Saxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_XSLT)
- [Apache Xerces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Xerces)

The only one that's open source is Xerces.

Comment: Links would make this a better answer.

Comment: Feel free to improve my answers if you wish.

Comment: The point is that it is your answer. I don't know these programs and would have to look up the sites to get links. So would every other person reading your answer. You know these programs and could easily add the links making the answer so much more convenient for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `xmlschema` written in `Python` can help you out.

https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/

> The xmlschema library is an implementation of XML Schema for Python (supports Python 3.5+).
>
> This library arises from the needs of a solid Python layer for
> processing XML Schema based files for MaX (Materials design at the
> Exascale) European project. A significant problem is the encoding and
> the decoding of the XML data files produced by different simulation
> software. Another important requirement is the XML data validation, in
> order to put the produced data under control. The lack of a suitable
> alternative for Python in the schema-based decoding of XML data has
> led to build this library. Obviously this library can be useful for
> other cases related to XML Schema based processing, not only for the
> original scope.
>
> The full xmlschema documentation is available on “Read the Docs”.

Answer (score -1):

[XMLStar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php) looks like a good candidate for your request.

It seems to be able to validate via command line so you should be able to script it.
It validates XSD if you define the xsd file.
I am not sure about the license but it's free and the source code is available.
Also it's available for

- Windows
- Linux
- Solaris

Comment: XMLStarlet is a command line interface to the libxml2/libxslt engines, which haven't been upgraded for many years and don't support XSD 1.1